# Lonely Integer Specific Solution

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

The Lonely Integer assumes an array with an odd number of elements. With every element occurring twice except for one element. The task is to find this 'lonely' element.

Within the Discussion section on HackerRank for this challenge, a working solution was suggested

```
int lonelyinteger(vector<int> a) {
    int r = 0;
    for (auto v : a) {
        r ^= v;
    }
    return r;
}
```

I am trying to understand this solution and added console output during each step to try to see what is going on, but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

`^` is the XOR operator but I do not understand how `^=` would work.

In addition to this, the condition within the for loop is hard for me to understand as well. Is there a more beginner way to write this? I assume that it is simply iterating through the array?

Comment: Does it help if you know that every integer value XOR'd with *itself* is zero ? And any value N XOR'd with zero is N. Think about that.

Comment: `r ^= v` === `r = r ^ v`

Comment: I would consider the range-based for loop as the "beginner" method. And if you know what `^` and `+=` are, figuring out `^=` shouldn't be a big jump.

Answer (score 4):

First, understand that XOR carries several properties you're probably familiar with. But in case your not

1. **Identity**: N ^ 0 == N
2. **Self-inverse**: N ^ N == 0
3. **Associative**: A ^ (B ^ C) == (A ^ B) ^ C
4. **Commutative**: A ^ B == B ^ A

Now, consider we have a sequence of, say five elements:

```
a b c a b
```

XOR'ing these in sequence yields (obviously):

```
a ^ b ^ c ^ a ^ b
```

Now, per the properties previously described this can be rewritten as:

```
a ^ a ^ b ^ b ^ c
```

However, we already know that `a ^ a` is zero (0), and likewise for `b ^ b`.  Therefore, this becomes.

```
0 ^ 0 ^ c
```

which becomes

```
0 ^ c
```

which finally becomes

```
c
```

The odd-man out.

Regarding what operator `^=` does. It is nothing more than shorthand for modify-and-store. E.g.

```
r ^= v
```

is equivalent to:

```
r = r ^ v
```